# A unit of time $\frac{GM}{c^3}$

Tags: black-holes, time, dimensional-analysis, simulations, units

I have come across a time unit $M$ that should be equal to $\frac{GM}{c^3}$. I cannot find anything at all about this anywhere.

I came across it while doing flux analysis on the flux from black hole simulations, MAD and SANE simulations, to be precise. Here the axis is flux [Jy] vs. time [M].

I have never come across this way of expressing time before.

I do get natural units. What I don't get is how does $\frac{GM}{c^3}$ become a unit of time? To me, it still seems like a unit of distance regardless of what $G$ and $c$ are.

Comment: So $\frac{R_S}{2c}$. Which reference? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic I have no reference to it, unfortunately, other than my professor. He's out of town currently, so I can't get a better explanation.

Comment: What's your actual question? It's pretty common in black hole work to use units where $G=1, c=1$, so distances & times are expressed in terms of $M$. (Personally, I find it less disorienting to use $r_s=1$).

Comment: @PM2Ring That I do get natural units. What i dont get is, how does it become a unit of time? to me, it still seems like a unit of distance regardless of what G and c is.

Comment: Distance divided by speed gives time. This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis If you're still puzzled, I can write an answer.

Comment: @PM2Ring That would be very helpful. It makes sense, to some extent, what you're saying, but I don't think I fully get it.

Comment: Since a rational choice of units implies G=1 and c=1, the "unit of time" that you are claiming becomes... M. To me that sounds meaningless. Is M the mass of a black hole? So the unit of time becomes dependent on the specific black hole? That's a very poor simulation strategy for numerical problems IMHO. One should scale the problem first and then simulate the scaled problem with unit steps.

Comment: *it still seems like a unit of distance* Why? Did you actually calculate the units of $GM/c^3$? Did you get meters or did you get seconds?

Comment: @FlatterMann The point is usually that GR is scale invariant, so the $M$ factors out of every actual calculation.

Comment: @TimRias That's why G=1 and c=1. M=1 is generally not possible because there are systems with two or more different masses and the mass ratios are unitless and hence physically relevant. Two colliding black holes with equal masses are not the same as a system with a 5:1 mass ratio.

Comment: @FlatterMann but $M$ is always the total mass...

Comment: @TimRias Even then the ratio of the partial masses defines the scaled dynamics of the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We first encounter $G$ in Newton's universal gravitation law:
$$F = \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$$

Applying [dimensional analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis),
$$MLT^{-2} = GM^2L^{-2}$$
so $G$ must have units of $M^{-1}L^3T^{-2}$.

A fundamental equation in General Relativity is the equation for the Schwarzschild radius:
$$r_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2}$$
We can readily see that the equation is dimensionally consistent:
$$L = \frac{M^{-1}L^3T^{-2}\cdot M}{(LT^{-1})^2}$$

It's a frequent practice in GR to use "natural" units such that $G$ and $c$ are both numerically equal to $1$. Using natural units, that equation simplifies to
$$r_s = 2M$$
but it's important to be able to restore the units, especially when performing numerical calculations where we want a result that relates to observable data written using SI or other conventional units.

When we do dimensional analysis on $\frac{GM}{c^3}$ we get
$$\frac{M^{-1}L^3T^{-2}\cdot M}{(LT^{-1})^3} = T$$
so that expression certainly has units of time. In natural units, the expression simplifies to $M$, but we need to remember that the units coming from $G$ and $c$ are "hiding" in that expression.

---

Personally, I find using $M$ for distance and time a little disorienting, and when working in the Schwarzschild metric I prefer to use $r_s=1$ and $u=\frac{r_s}r$, but the $M$ convention is quite common in the literature, so we just have to get used to it. ;) And as Tim Rias points out in the comments, $r_s=1$ is problematic when you *aren't* working in a strict Schwarzschild metric.

Comment: Ah in that way. Thank you, it makes sense now.

Comment: The setting $r_s=1$ convention is super confusing when dealing with anything other than Schwarzschild. I'd consider it a bad habit.

Comment: Fair point, @Tim I'm not advocating its general use, but it is handy if you're *only* working in Schwarzschild.

Comment: Still, at some point you might want to generalize to Kerr (or binaries etc.) at which point the $r_s=1$ choice will bite you. Better use $r_s=2$ like sane people do ;-).

Comment: Ok, @TimRias, I've updated that part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We know that in a Frenet frame of reference, the centrifugal force is :  $a_{n}=\frac{v^{2}}{r}=g=\frac{GM}{r^{2}}$

Assuming $\;\;v=c$ and $r=ct$,the previous equation becomes:$$t=\frac{GM}{c^{3}} $$
For me, it's just a way of looking at the content of the equation from a dimensional point of view.

Answer (score 0):

The Schwarzschld radius (a length) is $r_s=2GM/c^2$. So $GM/c^3$ is $r_s/2c$ (i.e. a length divided by a speed) and is thus clearly a timescale and one which is obviously useful when studying compact objects and black holes.